# Как воспользоваться лямбда-выражением для 'многометодных' интерфейсов?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется метод main(), в рамках которого вызывается метод run():

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new WorkTable().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

NetBeans предложил заменить анонимный класс лямбда-выражением:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new WorkTable().setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Поскольку метод run() - единственный в интерфейсе Runnable, речь идет именно о его реализации. Но как, в таком случае, воспользоваться лямбда-выражением если у интерфейса имеется несколько методов (к примеру, List)?

Благодарю.

Comment: Никак, это не Functional Interface по определению

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23373921/5661663

Comment: Согласен, все что не относится к функциональным интерфейсам, не попадает под такого рода упрощение.

Comment: @Etki, а почему тогда у меня код из моего ответа работает?..

Comment: Наверное, дело в том, что сигнатура в моём случае у всех методов различна

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. В документации [чётко сказано](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), что лямбда выражения могут быть использованы только для интерфейсов, имеющих один-единственный метод. 
На самом деле, лямбда выражения - просто синтаксический сахара (более читабельный и удобный синтаксис) для анонимных классов. Так что, работайте по-старинке (как в первом куске кода).

Comment: Полностью согласен, благодарю.